# word clustering in java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

I am having a text file which is of very big size.
I want to cluster that file, for example
if I want to divide the file in 5 cluster then
from A to Z the word frequency then the centroid of each cluster should be c,h,m,r,w
so the output should be like
initially all words are of a,b,c,d,e
then f,g,h,i,j
then k,l.m.n.o
then p,q,r,s,t
then u,v,w,x,y and z

I want to implement this type of clustering in java.
I have searched the code but I could not found word clustering program in java.

Comment: Your "very big" probably still can easily be processed in memory, without clustering, if you have a good implementation. But we don't know where your problem is, because you don't show any code.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.I have done coding for k-means clustering in java but its only work with numeric.

Comment: Here is the code for that

Answer (score 0):

Well, but my first word is, what have your tried so far, where is your code? And then, i think you know that anyone here will not go to do code for you until you show them your effort. Finding some reference of clustering isn't so difficult like [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=word+clustering+in+java).
Some good reference for you to start:

- [Github:word-clustering](https://github.com/mojtaba-khallash/word-clustering)
- [Google Code on word-clustering](http://code.google.com/p/word-clustering/source/browse/trunk/src/WordnetUtil.java?spec=svn67&r=67)

Find how they implement clustering and then apply your algorithm there.

Answer (score 0):

A well established Java library for machine-learning/data-mining is [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). It comes with a few different types of clustering techniques you could experiment with, and the API for these is [documented here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/package-summary.html).

Their download page comes with various platform-specific versions with installers, etc., but I'd recommend just downloading the [zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/weka/weka-3-6-10.zip), extract the jar and then use that (ie add to classpath) like you would any other jar and then you get full access to the Weka modules/API.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
    import java.util.*;
    class k_means
    {
static int count1,count2,count3;
static int d[];
static int k[][];
static int tempk[][];
static double m[];
static double diff[];
static int n,p;
static int cal_diff(int a) 
{
int temp1=0;
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
{
if(a>m[i])
diff[i]=a-m[i];
else
diff[i]=m[i]-a;
}
int val=0;
double temp=diff[0];
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
{
if(diff[i]<temp)
{
temp=diff[i];
val=i;
}
}
return val;
    }
static void cal_mean() 
{
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
m[i]=0; 
int cnt=0;
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
{
cnt=0;
for(int j=0;j<n-1;++j)
{
if(k[i][j]!=-1)
{
m[i]+=k[i][j];
++cnt;
}
}
m[i]=m[i]/cnt;
}
}
static int check1()
{
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
if(tempk[i][j]!=k[i][j])
{
return 0;
}
return 1;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of elements ");
n=scr.nextInt();
d=new int[n];
System.out.println("Enter "+n+" elements: ");
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
d[i]=scr.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the number of clusters: ");
p=scr.nextInt();
k=new int[p][n];
tempk=new int[p][n];
m=new double[p];
diff=new double[p];
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
m[i]=d[i];
int temp=0;
int flag=0;
do
{
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
{   
k[i][j]=-1;
}
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) 
{
temp=cal_diff(d[i]);
if(temp==0)
k[temp][count1++]=d[i];
else
if(temp==1)
k[temp][count2++]=d[i];
else
if(temp==2)
k[temp][count3++]=d[i]; 
}
cal_mean();
flag=check1();
if(flag!=1)
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
tempk[i][j]=k[i][j];
System.out.println("\n\nAt this step");
System.out.println("\nValue of clusters");
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
{
System.out.print("K"+(i+1)+"{ ");
for(int j=0;k[i][j]!=-1 && j<n-1;++j)
System.out.print(k[i][j]+" ");
System.out.println("}");
}
System.out.println("\nValue of m ");
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
System.out.print("m"+(i+1)+"="+m[i]+"  ");
count1=0;count2=0;count3=0;
}
while(flag==0);
System.out.println("\n\n\nThe Final Clusters By Kmeans are as follows: ");
for(int i=0;i<p;++i)
{
System.out.print("K"+(i+1)+"{ ");
for(int j=0;k[i][j]!=-1 && j<n-1;++j)
System.out.print(k[i][j]+" ");
System.out.println("}");
}
}
    }
```